# Prevent deployment to entry node, only deploy to other nodes

Tags: jboss, openshift, wildfly-8

I have a free OpenShift account with the default 3 gears. On this I have installed the WildFly 8.1 image using the OpenShift web console. I set the minimal and maximal scaling to 3.

What happens now is that OpenShift will create 3 JBoss WildFly instances:

- One on the entry node (which is also running HAProxy)
- One on an auxiliary node
- One on another auxiliary node

The weird thing is that the JBoss WildFly instance on the entry node is by default disabled in the load balancer config (haproxy.conf). BUT, OpenShift is still deploying the war archive to it whenever I commit in the associated git repo.

What's extra problematic here is that because of the incredibly low number of max user processes (250 via ulimit -u), this JBoss WildFly instance on the entry node cannot even startup. During startup JBoss WildFly will throw random 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread' (*and no, memory is fine, it's the OS process limit*).

As a result, the deployment process will hang.

So to summarize:

- A JBoss WildFly instance is created on the entry node, but disabled in the load balancer
- JBoss WildFly in its default configuration cannot startup on the entry node, not even with a trivial war.
- The deployer process attempts to deploy to JBoss WildFly on the entry node, despite it being disabled in the load balancer

Now my question:

How can I modify the deployer process (including the `gear start` command) to not attempt to deploy to the JBoss WildFly instance on the entry node?

Answer (score 0):

When an app scales from 2 gears to 3, HAproxy stops routing traffic to your application on the headgear and routes it to the two other gears. This assures that HAproxy is getting the most CPU as possible as the application on your headgear (where HAproxy is running) is no longer serving requests.

The out of memory message you're seeing might not be an actual out of memory issue but a bug relating to ulimit https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1090092.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already knew it was not an actual OOM, see this part in my question: 'and no, memory is fine, it's the OS process limit).' ;)

Comment: "Once it does that is disables anything else from running in that gear so that HAproxy gets all the resources. " - It's clear this is happening, but if you go straight to 3 gears (fixed; min 3, max 3), why is the JBoss instance even there? And why is it started and being deployed to if it's disabled? It's now taking up resources anyway, even though no traffic is being routed to it :(

Comment: So you're correct it doesn't *completely* get all the resources. Basically when an app is scaling from 2 gears to 3, HAProxy will stop routing traffic to the application on your head gear and start routing it to the other 2. This assures that the application on your head gear isn't using as much CPU which is what HAProxy needs most (memory usage of HAproxy is quite minimal). I'll revise my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the revision, but still don't understand the logic of keeping the application running, but not routing traffic to it. This is even weirder when you -start- with 3 gears. Then the app on the head gear has never seen any traffic to begin with.